# Задача поиска в цепочке

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict

Есть 3 словаря:
Словарь 1:

```
list_of_first_currencys
```

```
{'ADA': 'TUSD', 'ALGO': 'TUSD', 'BCH': 'TUSD', 'BNB': 'TUSD', 'BTC': 'TUSD', 
 'BTT': 'TUSD', 'EOS': 'TUSD', 'ETH': 'TUSD', 'LINK': 'TUSD', 'LTC': 'TUSD', 
 'PHB': 'TUSD', 'TRX': 'TUSD', 'XRP': 'TUSD'}
```

Словарь 2:

```
list_of_second_currencys
```

```
 {'BTG': 'BTC', 'BTS': 'BTC', 'BTT': 'BNB', 'BURGER': 'BNB', 'BZRX': 'BTC', 
 'CAKE': 'BNB', 'CDT': 'BTC', 'CELO': 'BTC', 'CELR': 'BTC', 'CHR': 'BTC', 'CHZ': 
 'BTC', 'CKB': 'BTC', 'CND': 'BTC', 'COCOS': 'BNB', 'COMP': 'BTC', 'COS': 'BTC', 
 'COTI': 'BTC', 'CREAM': 'BNB', 'CRV': 'BTC', 'CTK': 'BTC', 'CTSI': 'BTC', 
 'CTXC': 'BTC', 'CVC': 'BTC', 'DASH': 'BTC', 'DATA': 'BTC', 'DCR': 'BTC', 'DGB': 
 'BTC', 'DIA': 'BTC', 'DLT': 'BTC', 'DNT': 'BTC', 'DOCK': 'BTC', 'DOGE': 'BTC', 
 'DOT': 'BTC', 'DREP': 'BTC', 'DUSK': 'BTC', 'EGLD': 'BTC', 'ELF': 'BTC', 'ENJ': 
 'BTC', 'EOS': 'BTC', 'ETC': 'BNB', 'EVX': 'BTC', 'FET': 'BTC', 'FIL': 'BTC', 
 'FIO': 'BTC', 'FIRO': 'ETH', 'FLM': 'BTC', 'FOR': 'BTC', 'FRONT': 'ETH', 'FTM': 
 'BTC', 'FTT': 'BTC', 'FUN': 'BTC', 'GHST': 'ETH', 'GLM': 'ETH', 'GO': 'BTC', 
 'GRS': 'BTC', 'GRT': 'ETH', 'GTO': 'BTC', 'GVT': 'BTC', 'GXS': 'ETH', 'HARD': 
 'BTC', 'HBAR': 'BTC', 'HEGIC': 'ETH', 'HIVE': 'BTC', 'HNT': 'BTC', 'HOT': 'ETH', 
 'ICX': 'ETH', 'IDEX': 'BTC', 'INJ': 'BTC', 'IOST': 'ETH', 'IOTA': 'BNB', 'IOTX': 
 'ETH', 'IQ': 'BNB', 'IRIS': 'BTC', 'JST': 'BTC', 'JUV': 'BTC', 'KAVA': 'BTC', 
 'KEY': 'ETH', 'KMD': 'ETH', 'KP3R': 'BNB', 'KSM': 'BTC', 'LIT': 'BTC', 'LOOM': 'ETH', 'LRC': 'ETH', 'LSK': 'ETH', 'LTC': 'ETH', 'LTO': 'BTC', 'LUNA': 'BTC', 
 'MANA': 'ETH', 'MATIC': 'BTC', 'MBL': 'BNB', 'MDA': 'BTC', 'MDT': 'BTC', 'MFT': 
 'ETH', 'MITH': 'BTC', 'MKR': 'BTC', 'MTH': 'BTC', 'MTL': 'ETH', 'NANO': 'ETH', 
 'NAS': 'ETH', 'NAV': 'BTC', 'NBS': 'BTC', 'NCASH': 'ETH', 'NEAR': 'BTC', 'NEBL': 
 'ETH', 'NEO': 'BNB', 'NKN': 'BTC', 'NMR': 'BTC', 'NPXS': 'ETH', 'NXS': 'BTC', 
 'OAX': 'BTC', 'OCEAN': 'BTC', 'OG': 'BTC', 'OGN': 'BTC', 'ONE': 'BTC', 'ONG': 
 'BTC', 'ONT': 'ETH', 'ORN': 'BTC', 'OST': 'ETH', 'OXT': 'BTC', 'PAXG': 'BTC', 
 'PERL': 'BTC', 'PHB': 'BTC', 'PIVX': 'ETH', 'PNT': 'BTC', 'POA': 'BTC', 'POLY': 
 'BTC', 'POWR': 'ETH', 'PPT': 'BTC', 'PROM': 'BNB', 'PROS': 'ETH', 'PSG': 'BTC', 
 'QKC': 'ETH', 'QLC': 'ETH', 'QSP': 'ETH', 'RCN': 'BTC', 'RDN': 'BTC', 'REEF': 
 'BTC', 'REN': 'BTC', 'RENBTC': 'ETH', 'REP': 'ETH', 'REQ': 'BTC', 'RIF': 'BTC', 
 'RLC': 'ETH', 'ROSE': 'BTC', 'RSR': 'BTC', 'RUNE': 'BTC', 'RVN': 'BTC', 'SAND': 
 'BTC', 'SC': 'ETH', 'SCRT': 'ETH', 'SKL': 'BTC', 'SKY': 'BTC', 'SLP': 'ETH', 
 'SNT': 'BTC', 'SNX': 'BTC', 'SOL': 'BTC', 'SPARTA': 'BNB', 'SRM': 'BTC', 
 'STEEM': 'ETH', 'STMX': 'ETH', 'STORJ': 'BTC', 'STPT': 'BTC', 'STRAX': 'ETH', 
 'STX': 'BTC', 'SUN': 'BTC', 'SUSD': 'ETH', 'SUSHI': 'BTC', 'SWRV': 'BNB', 'SXP': 
 'BTC', 'SYS': 'BTC', 'TCT': 'BTC', 'TFUEL': 'BTC', 'THETA': 'ETH', 'TNB': 'BTC', 
 'TOMO': 'BTC', 'TRB': 'BTC', 'TROY': 'BTC', 'TRU': 'BTC', 'TRX': 'ETH', 'TWT': 'BTC', 'UMA': 
 'BTC', 'UNFI': 'BTC', 'UNI': 'BTC', 'UTK': 'BTC', 'VET': 'ETH', 'VIA': 'BTC', 
 'VIB': 'ETH', 'VIBE': 'BTC', 'VIDT': 'BTC', 'VITE': 'BTC', 'VTHO': 'BNB', 
 'WABI': 'BTC', 'WAN': 'ETH', 'WAVES': 'ETH', 'WBTC': 'ETH', 'WIN': 'TRX', 
 'WING': 'BTC', 'WNXM': 'BTC', 'WPR': 'BTC', 'WRX': 'BTC',
 'WTC': 'BNB', 'XEM': 'ETH', 'XLM': 'ETH', 'XMR': 'ETH', 'XRP': 'ETH', 'XTZ': 
 'BTC', 'XVG': 'BTC', 'XVS': 'BTC', 'XZC': 'ETH', 'YFI': 'BTC', 'YFII': 'BTC', 
 'YOYO': 'BTC', 'ZEC': 'ETH', 'ZEN': 'ETH', 'ZIL': 'ETH', 'BAL': 'BTC', 'ANT': 
 'BTC'}
```

Словарь 3:

```
list_of_third_currencys
```

```
 {'BTT': 'TUSD', 'EOS': 'TUSD', 'LTC': 'TUSD', 'PHB': 'TUSD', 'TRX': 'TUSD', 
 'XRP': 'TUSD'}
```

Нужно получить словарь по следующему принципу:
Если ключ из 3-го словаря есть в ключе из 2-го словаря и его значение (значение из 2-го словаря) есть в ключе 1-го словаря, то нужно все три пары "ключ-значение" добавить в словарь по принципу {"ключ" 1-го словаря: ["ключ-значение" 2-го словаря, "ключ-значение" 3-го словаря]}

UPD Пример результата.

```
{'BNB': {'BTT': 'BNB', 'BTT': 'TUSD'}}
```

Моя попытка

```
voc = {}
    for key, value in list_of_third_currencys.items():

        if key in list_of_second_currencys.keys() and value in list_of_first_currencys.keys():
            voc.update({value[list_of_second_currencys.items()
            ,list_of_third_currencys.items()]})
```

UPD 2. Почти решил. Не могу понять, как теперь элементы добавить в словарь.

```
 for key, value in list_of_second_currencys.items():
        if key in list_of_third_currencys.keys():
            if value in list_of_first_currencys.keys():
                voc.update.....
```

Comment: Блин, что не так с вопросом. Я его минут 20 формулировал, чтобы было понятно...

Comment: нет таких структур в пайтоне: {'BNB': 'TUSD':['BTT': 'BNB', 'BTT': 'TUSD']} ... вот так: {"ключ-значение" 1-го словаря: {"ключ-значение" 2-го словаря, "ключ-значение" 3-го словаря}} еще куда б не шло...

Comment: Спасибо за прошлый ответ Джек! Что имеется в виду? Словарь не может быть создан по такому принципу?

Comment: Дак я же так и написал? Извините, запарился сегодня.

Comment: да, {key: value}, но не {key: otherkey: value}

Comment: Немного поправлю Ваш итог должно быть что-то такое.. {'BNB':{'BTT': 'BNB', 'BTT': 'TUSD'}}, [] - список а содержимое у Вас словарь. Попробуйте циклами сравнивайте значения при выполнении условия добавляете. Предоставьте хотя-бы попытку реализации

Comment: Так, сейчас. Я, видимо перемудрил. Переформулирую вопрос. Спасибо!

Comment: Да, вы правы. USDT тут не к чему. Это и так очевидно.

Comment: Я по ошибке запихал в ключ словаря и значение тоже. Понял.

Comment: По прежнему испытываю сложности с обращением к элементам словаря. Надо попроще задачи научиться решать сначала.

Comment: Добавил вариант. Ни одной ошибки) Что меня удивило) Но словарь пустой)

Comment: перечитал 5 раз, ничего не понял. можете пример как-то уменьшить, чтобы было понятней и принцип тоже описан невнятно

Comment: у вас в примере результата все еще два одинаковых ключа: ```{'BNB': {'BTT': 'BNB', 'BTT': 'TUSD'}}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере используется неподходящая структура данных в определённом месте.

```
{'BNB': {'BTT': 'BNB', 'BTT': 'TUSD'}}
```

Вы хотите получать словарь, где один и тот же ключ будет повторяться. Это неправитьно - использование словаря предполагает, что все ключи уникальны. Я могу посоветовать вам использование списка внутри. Пример

```
{'BNB': ['BNB', 'TUSD']}
```

Код, который вам нужен:

dn - словари, где 1<=n<=3

```
for key in d3.keys(): 
     if key in d2 and d3[key] in d1: 
         result_dict.update({d1[key]: [d2[key], d3[key]]})
```